# Error When trying to Create a Header in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to replicate a LinkedIn concept on a project that I am working on. Using the Icons in the Header to send me to a new page. I am using material UI for the ICONS but seem to be getting an error that has to do with importing. I am place the errors below, and then I will place the code for the header, headerOptions, and app.js, please let me know if I can place anything more to help with figuring out the issue. I did not place all the errors, or it would be to long, the error repeats for lines 29-48 in the navbar.js file.

Errors

```
    Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at navbar.js:31.
    at Header
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:85592:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:85212:35)
    at PersistGate (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:91701:5)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:82612
```

:20)
at App (http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:340:1)

navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import './navbar.style.scss'
import HeaderOption from './navbarOption'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
// import logo from '../../../assets/openOceanLogo.png'
import "./navbar.style.scss";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import SupervisorAccountIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SupervisorAccount";
import BusinessCenterIcon from "@material-ui/icons/BusinessCenter";
import ChatIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Chat";
import NotificationsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";


function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header__left">
        <img
          src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/174/174857.svg"
          alt="linkedin logo"
        />
        <div className="header__search">
          <SearchIcon />
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="header__right">
        <Link to="/home">
        <HeaderOption Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/search">
        <HeaderOption Icon={SupervisorAccountIcon} title="Search" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/network">
        <HeaderOption Icon={BusinessCenterIcon} title="Network" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/message">
        <HeaderOption Icon={ChatIcon} title="Messaging" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/notifications">
        <HeaderOption Icon={NotificationsIcon} title="Notifications" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/Login">
        <HeaderOption avatar={true} title="Log Out" />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

navbarOptions.js

```
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import "./navbarOptions.style.scss";

export default function HeaderOption({ avatar, Icon, title }) {
  return (
    <div className="headerOption">
      {Icon && <Icon className="headerOption__icon" />}
      {avatar && <Avatar className="headerOption__icon"> ⬇</Avatar>}
      <h3 className="headerOption__title">{title}</h3>
    </div>
```

App.JS

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import{ Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store, persistor } from './Redux/store'
import './App.css';
import Header from "./components/menu/navBar/navbar";
import Home from './pages/home/home'
import search from './pages/search/search'
import VentureVault from "./pages/venturevault/ventureVault";
import Query from './pages/query/query'
import Visualize from "./pages/visualize/visualize";
import Analyze from "./pages/analyze/analyze";
import Configure from "./pages/configure/configure";




class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact/>
                <Route path="/search" component={search} exact/>
                <Route path="/network" component={Query} exact/>
                <Route path="/profile" component={Visualize} exact/>
                <Route path="/notifications" component={Analyze} exact/>
                <Route path="/message" component={Configure} exact/>
                <Route path="/venture" component={VentureVault} exact/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error you are seeing. Can you create a sandbox or github repo with minimal code? There might be problems with MUI installation.